# Как получить ref компонентов детей?

Tags: reactjs

Вывожу элементы.   А как получить доступ к компоненту после того как он был выведен на экран?

```
 render() {

      return (
        <g>
          {this.props.children}
        </g>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При рендере можно указать `ref` компонента как [callback-функцию](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), в которой сохранить указатель на компонент в свойстве класса. После чего обращаться к нему как по имени свойства

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    childRef1;
    childRef2;

    someActionByRef () {
        this.childRef1.someMethodOfChildComponent();
        this.childRef2.someMethodOfChildComponent();
    }

    render () {
        <ChildComponent
            ref={childRef => this.childRef1 = childRef}
        />
        <ChildComponent
            ref={childRef => this.childRef2 = childRef}
        />
    }
}
```

Comment: А как это указать для  {this.props.children}?

Comment: для `{this.props.children}` никак

Comment: конечная цель какая? что нужно делать с детьми по refs?

Comment: А как это можно переписать? 

Получить детей и их координаты и расставить их по новым координатам.

Comment: дети одного класса? или в качестве детей все что угодно вперемешку?

Comment: Одного класса используются.

Answer (score 1):

В ответ на комментарий

> *Получить детей и их координаты и расставить их по новым координатам*

Лучше не пытаться получать "детей" по `ref`, а держать координаты объектов в `state` и отрисовывать "детей" в соответствии со `state`

Пример со случайным увеличением координат надписей. Нажмите "выполнить код" и покликайте на кнопке

```js
class ChildItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        style={{
          position: "absolute", 
          top: this.props.top, 
          left: this.props.left
        }}
      >
        Item {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      childs: [
         {
           top: 40,
           left: 20,
           name: "First"
         },
         {
           top: 60,
           left: 30,
           name: "Second"
         }
      ]
    }
  }
  
  onButtonClick = () => {
    let next = this.state.childs.map((item, i, arr) => {
       item.top += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
       item.left += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
       return item;
    });
    
    this.setState({
      childs: next
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const items = this.state.childs.map((element, index) => 
       <ChildItem
          top={element.top}
          left={element.left}
          name={element.name}
          key={index}
       />
    );
    return(
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={this.onButtonClick}
      >
        Move items
      </button>
      <div className="itemClass">
      {items}
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.itemClass {
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```